# How to change the public url of picasa album

Tags: google-plus, picasa-web-albums

My picasa web album is linked to my google plus account. My public url has a long string of unique numbers on it . My Question is how do we change the string of numbers to my gmail account username.

I have been searching for this this the whole day but couldnt find the option

currently its `https://picasaweb.google.com/111293829763795395367` i want it to be like this `https://picasaweb.google.com/mevinbabuc`

Answer (score 1):

1. Sign in to Picasa Web Albums.
2. Click the gear icon in the top-right corner and choose Photos
   settings.
3. Under ‘Your Gallery URL,’ click Want to add a new Google username?
4. Under ‘Add a new username,’ enter your desired username.  Click Add
   username.

[Source](http://support.google.com/picasa/answer/187292/?hl=en-GB&)

Comment: i can see the `Your Gallery URL` part but i dont see the `click to add a new google username` . Guess they removed the option to change the url long back .